# Why is the third column so wide?

Tags: tabularx

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}



\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{100pt}{c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ } &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$r$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$b$} \\ \cline{2-3}
$r$ & $\frac{4}{9}$ & $\frac{2}{9}$  \\ \cline{2-3}
$b$ & $\frac{2}{9}$ & $\frac{1}{9}$   \\ \cline{2-3} \multicolumn{3}{c}{2 red 1 blue}
\end{tabularx}\hskip 1.7cm 
\begin{tabularx}{100pt}{c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ } &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$r$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$b$} \\ \cline{2-3}
$r$ & $\frac{1}{9}$ & $\frac{2}{9}$  \\ \cline{2-3}
$b$ & $\frac{2}{9}$ & $\frac{4}{9}$   \\ \cline{2-3} \multicolumn{3}{c}{2 blue 1 red}
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

My intention is to put "2 red 1 blue" below the subchart and in the middle of the subchart. But why is the third column so wide?

Comment: Using `tabularx` at least one column had to be of `X` type!.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get your point. Could you please elaborate on it?

Comment: THe point is, that using `tabularx` at list one column had to be (derived from) `X` type. in your case for example `\begin{tabularx}{100pt}{c | C|C|}` where is `C` is defined as `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}`. See my answer. For more details about `tabularx` package you can find in its documentation.

Comment: A related problem (not relevant here) is if a \multicolumn over several columns is wider than the combined columns, all the extra space is added to the last column.

Answer (score 4):

As I said in comment, at least one column in `tabularx` tables had to of `X` type. This means, that in your case table should be for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}%
                                 {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{100pt}{c | C|C|}
\mcc{}  & \mcc{$r$}     & \mcc{$b$}     \\
    \cline{2-3}
$r$     & $\frac{4}{9}$ & $\frac{2}{9}$ \\
    \cline{2-3}
$b$     & $\frac{2}{9}$ & $\frac{1}{9}$ \\
    \cline{2-3}
\mcc[3]{2 red 1 blue}
\end{tabularx}
    \hskip 21mm
\begin{tabularx}{100pt}{C | C|C|}
\mcc{}  & \mcc{$r$}     & \mcc{$b$}     \\
    \cline{2-3}
$r$     & $\frac{4}{9}$ & $\frac{2}{9}$ \\
    \cline{2-3}
$b$     & $\frac{2}{9}$ & $\frac{1}{9}$ \\
    \cline{2-3}
\mcc[3]{2 red 1 blue}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, in the first table has the second and third column equal width but with narrower first, in the second table all columns have equal width.

Columns `c`, `l` and `r` has width of the widest width of cells content in column. Contrary, at `tabularx` you must prescribe table width and at least one column width in table must be calculated by LaTeX. This functionality has columns  `X` od columns derived from it (for centering, left or right align cell content). If this is not enabled, usually `\hline` or `\cline` protrude out of table (so you lucky that this not hapen at your cases).

However, when you have `\multicolumn` cells, which content is wider than sum of natural width spanned columns, than last column width is increased for amount dictated by width of `\multicolumn` cell. Consequently you should care that not happen (define bigger width of spanned columns).

To my opinion, your tables will be nicer, if you would use `tabularray` package and center ˙\multicolum` cell below last two columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{hline{2-Y}={2-Z}{solid},
             vline{2-Z}={2-Y}{solid}, 
             colspec={c *{2}{Q[c,wd=2em,mode=math]}},  
             row{Z} = {mode=text},
             rowsep=3pt
             }
    &       r       &   b           \\ 
r   & \frac{4}{9}   & \frac{2}{9}   \\ 
b   & \frac{2}{9}   & \frac{1}{9}   \\ 
    & \SetCell[c=2]{c}    2 red 1 blue 
\end{tblr}
    \hskip 21mm
\begin{tblr}{hline{2-Y}={2-Z}{solid},
             vline{2-Z}={2-Y}{solid},
             colspec={c *{2}{Q[c,wd=2em,mode=math]}},
             row{Z} = {mode=text},
             rowsep=3pt
             }
    &       r       &   b           \\
r   & \frac{4}{9}   & \frac{2}{9}   \\
b   & \frac{2}{9}   & \frac{1}{9}   \\
    & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  2 red 1 blue
\end{tblr}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
It seems that till now Overleaf still not refresh their package repository. Hopefully this will do in near features. Until than you can use "classic" approach by use of `array` and `makecell` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}%
                                 {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{c | *{2}{>{$}w{c}{2em}<{$} |}}
\mcc{}  & \mcc{$r$}     & \mcc{$b$}     \\
    \cline{2-3}
r       & \frac{4}{9}   & \frac{2}{9}   \\
    \cline{2-3}
b       & \frac{2}{9}   & \frac{1}{9}   \\
    \cline{2-3}
\mcc{}  & \mcc[2]{2 red 1 blue}
\end{tabular}
    \hskip 21mm
\begin{tabular}{c | *{2}{>{$}w{c}{2em}<{$} |}}
\mcc{}  & \mcc{$r$}     & \mcc{$b$}     \\
    \cline{2-3}
r       & \frac{4}{9}   & \frac{2}{9}   \\
    \cline{2-3}
b       & \frac{2}{9}   & \frac{1}{9}   \\
    \cline{2-3}
\mcc[3]{2 red 1 blue}
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Compilation result is very similar as at use of the `tabularray` package.

[image]

Both tables, for sake of style comparison,  differ slightly. At the first, the text "2 red 1 blue" is below the second and third columns, and at the second, is under all three columns.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I cannot compile your last set of codes on Overleaf.

Comment: @Ypbor, that is problem of Overleaf. Please ask them for help for use last version of `tabularray` package or when they will start to use TeXlive 2022 where it is present. For meanwhile you can stick with solution in addendum to answer.

Comment: In Addendum, why sometimes r and b are put in $$, but sometimes \frac{4}{9} is not?

Comment: @Ypbor, because second and third column are in mat mode. You ca change first row to text mode with table preamble option `row{1} = {mode=text}` .  Since last row already has such option, you can extend this alsoi to the firs row:  `row{1,Z} = {mode=text}` .

Comment: Thanks! Could you please also look at this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648669/how-to-draw-such-a-table-width-is-inflexible-in-the-original-answer

Comment: @Ypbor, your question is closed. Please consider comment below question.

Answer (score 2):

A comment up front: Since none of the columns in your sample tables would appear to require automatic line breaking within cells, I don't think it's a great idea to use a `tabularx` environment.

You asked,

> But why is the third column so wide?

First some terminology:

- The total width of a column of type `l`, `c`, or `r` is the sum of (a) the "natural" width of the widest cell in the column and (b) `2\tabcolsep` (or `2\arraycolsep` if an `array` environment is in use). The parameters `\tabcolsep` and `\arraycolsep` determine the amount of whitespace padding that LaTeX inserts at the edges of the column, depending on whether a `tabular`-like or an `array` environment is in use.
- The total width of a multi-column `tabular` or `array` environment is given, almost by definition, as the sum of the individual total column widths, plus the combined width of any vertical rules (if present).

Your `tabular` environments also contain the following 3-column entry:

```
\multicolumn{3}{c}{2 red 1 blue}
```

As you've "discovered", this item determines the overall or total width of the `tabular` environment. Since its width exceeds the sum of the three individual column widths, something has to give. The solution that LaTeX chooses is to allocate the excess width to the final column. While this choice may seem arbitrary, any other solution -- such as allocating the excess width in equal parts to each of the 3 columns -- would be just as arbitrary.

I take it that you wish the widths of columns 2 and 3 to be equal. Two choices let you achieve your goal: (a) increase the value of `\tabcolsep` (or `\arraycolsep`, if an `array` environment is in use), and/or (b) increase the column widths beyond their "natural" widths. Both possibilities are illustrated in the following screenshot, which contains three rows.

- The top row illustrates your initial setup. (To reduce code clutter and get rid of lots and lots of `$` symbols, I've switched from `tabular` to `array` environments). Clearly, column 3 is much wider than column 2.
- The middle row illustrates the effect of increasing the value of `\arraycolsep`, while keeping the basic `c` column type. Adding 5pt to the default value of `\arraycolsep` (which also happens to be 5pt) gets the job done. (Aside: This approach "works" because the natural widths of columns 2 and 3 are determined by the `\frac` terms, which happen to have equal widths.)
- The bottom row illustrates the effect of setting a fixed (usable) width of 14pt for columns 2 and 3 (by employing the `w` column type, which is provided by the `array` package), while using the default value of `\arraycolsep`. As long as the widths of the `wc` (where `c` stands for "center") columns are chosen "large enough" -- here, 14pt seems about right -- you will end up with a table whose 2nd and 3rd columns are equally wide.

Is one solution always better than the other? In general, no. For the specific case at hand, though, observe that the first solution method also ends up increasing the total width of column 1, while this isn't the case for the second. If maximal compactness of the first column is important to you, you may prefer to employ the second solution method.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type and \extrarowheight macro
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

Initial setup
\[
\begin{array}{ c | c | c | }
\mc{} & \mc{r} & \mc{b} \\ \cline{2-3}
r & \frac{4}{9} & \frac{2}{9}   \\ \cline{2-3}
b & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{1}{9}   \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{3}{>{$}c<{$}}{2 red 1 blue}
\end{array}
\hskip 1.7cm 
\begin{array}{ c | c | c | }
\mc{} & \mc{r} & \mc{b} \\ \cline{2-3}
r & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{2}{9}   \\ \cline{2-3}
b & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{4}{9}   \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{3}{>{$}c<{$}}{2 blue 1 red}
\end{array}
\]

\bigskip
Solution 1: Increase \texttt{\string\arraycolsep} or \texttt{\string\tabcolsep}
\[
\addtolength{\arraycolsep}{5pt} % default value: 5pt
\begin{array}{ c | c | c | }
\mc{} & \mc{r} & \mc{b} \\ \cline{2-3}
r & \frac{4}{9} & \frac{2}{9}   \\ \cline{2-3}
b & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{1}{9}   \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{3}{>{$}c<{$}}{2 red 1 blue}
\end{array}
\hskip 1.7cm 
\begin{array}{ c | c | c | }
\mc{} & \mc{r} & \mc{b} \\ \cline{2-3}
r & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{2}{9}   \\ \cline{2-3}
b & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{4}{9}   \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{3}{>{$}c<{$}}{2 blue 1 red}
\end{array}
\]

\bigskip
Solution 2: Increase usable column widths
\[
\begin{array}{ c |wc{14pt} | wc{14pt} | }
\mc{} & \mc{r} & \mc{b} \\ \cline{2-3}
r & \frac{4}{9} & \frac{2}{9}   \\ \cline{2-3}
b & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{1}{9}   \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{3}{>{$}c<{$}}{2 red 1 blue}
\end{array}
\hskip 1.7cm 
\begin{array}{ c |wc{14pt} | wc{14pt} | }
\mc{} & \mc{r} & \mc{b} \\ \cline{2-3}
r & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{2}{9}   \\ \cline{2-3}
b & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{4}{9}   \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{3}{>{$}c<{$}}{2 blue 1 red}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```